# TIFF file does not show on picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, tiff

I'm trying to show [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) files on a picturebox in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29). My code is here:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("someName.tif");
```

This code is working fine, but some TIFF file isn't displaying on the picturebox (the TIFF file isn't broken). What is wrong?

Comment: looks like it's not easy to solve, could you post some link to download that tiff file which the pictureBox can't display?

Comment: how do you know that the tiff file is not broken? Unfortunately, TIFF is one of those garbage standards where a file can meet the standard but is unreadable by most TIFF readers.

Comment: here is tiff file:
http://www.4shared.com/photo/r8UG8jsH/Invisible_201311222112972.html

Comment: thanks for replies. this tiff file is successfully displayed by another program. but i can not display this.

Comment: Solved :). Thanks all.

i used LibTiff:
http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/

Comment: I've tried opening that tiff file with some viewers and looks like they even can't open it but some others can, such as `Windows Photo Viewer` can't open it but `IrfanView` can.

Answer (score 0):

This TIFF file contains one color image compressed using JPEG 4:4:4.
Although Microsoft functions can handle some sub-types of TIFF, including some JPEG compressed varieties, this particular file uses a flavor of JPEG compression known as "old style". It appears Microsoft functions do not support this flavor.

If you need to load such files in your code, you might have to use a dedicated imaging library.